# Why is our Postgres query performance slow?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Running against both 9.6 and 10.

We started noticing issues with our query times we could resolve.  Through troubleshooting though we discovered that even simple queries are painfully slow.  The following query takes about 4 seconds to return the count.  Adding another left join kicks it up to 9 seconds.

```
select count(1)
from sales_lead sl  
inner join dealership d
   on d.id = sl.dealership_id
inner join dealership_group dg
   on d.dealership_group_id = dg.id 
left join customer_email ce
   on sl.customer_id = ce.customer_id
```

All the join columns have indexes on them.  All of the tables have been VACUUM ANALYZE.  The columns for each table are between 5 and 12.  The table counts are roughly as follows:

- sales_lead - '2113057'
- customer_email - '2270856'
- dealership_group - 4
- dealership - 23

I have noticed from the Database statistics that the Temporary files seem to be abnormally high as does the size of them.  The database itself is maybe 400 mb of data and yet the temp files are 117GB?  These numbers never seem to decrease.

Here is a snippet of the explain:
[image]

Text Version of explain (analyze, buffers)

```
'Aggregate  (cost=297026.78..297026.79 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5959.018..5959.018 rows=1 loops=1)'
'  Buffers: shared hit=1697364 read=193415'
'  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.78..291505.59 rows=2208477 width=0) (actual time=0.106..5735.227 rows=2298433 loops=1)'
'        Hash Cond: (sl.dealership_id = d.id)'
'        Buffers: shared hit=1697364 read=193415'
'        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.86..261136.11 rows=2208477 width=8) (actual time=0.030..5216.924 rows=2298433 loops=1)'
'              Merge Cond: (sl.customer_id = ce.customer_id)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=1697362 read=193415'
'              ->  Index Scan using fki_fk_customer_id on sales_lead sl  (cost=0.43..169112.10 rows=2113129 width=16) (actual time=0.010..3929.479 rows=2113057 loops=1)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=1695917 read=187211'
'              ->  Index Only Scan using idx_customer_email_customer_id on customer_email ce  (cost=0.43..58979.27 rows=2270856 width=4) (actual time=0.016..390.700 rows=2792048 loops=1)'
'                    Heap Fetches: 0'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=1445 read=6204'
'        ->  Hash  (cost=2.64..2.64 rows=23 width=4) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=23 loops=1)'
'              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB'
'              Buffers: shared hit=2'
'              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.09..2.64 rows=23 width=4) (actual time=0.046..0.051 rows=23 loops=1)'
'                    Hash Cond: (d.dealership_group_id = dg.id)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                    ->  Seq Scan on dealership d  (cost=0.00..1.23 rows=23 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=23 loops=1)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                          ->  Seq Scan on dealership_group dg  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=1'
'Planning time: 1.417 ms'
'Execution time: 5959.196 ms'
```

Here is a snippet of the statistics for the database:
[image]

Comment: One thing worth to try - when we switched from 9.5 to 9.6 and 10 we found that new versions require higher work_mem setting to give us the same performance. So maybe you could try to fiddle with this parameter a bit.

Comment: How long have the postgreSQL service have been running? weeks? months? if so, perhaps just needs a restart (of the service, maybe a reboot of the system to, but after is necesary to restart the service). PostgreSQL keeps its WAL for restoration, but with time it makes some parts of the database slower.

Comment: My local version that this is against has been around for maybe a week.  I've rebooted before, but I can try again.  Should I see any changes in the statistics afterwards?

Comment: Read through the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) link in the postgresql-performance tag I added.

Comment: did you copy postgres.conf over?..

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thank you, I didn't not see that tag before!  Much appreciated.